# php pagination with multiple $_GET variables

Tags: php, sql, get, pagination

Im trying to make Advanced Search engine for my website using the `$_GET[variable from url]` to pass the options the user selected in my search webpage.

I have these three options for user to search:

```
1. Search By Authors
2. Search By Category
3. Search By Language
4. Search By Keyword
```

below is the `$query`

```
$k  = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['k']);
$a  = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['a']);
$l  = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['l']);
$c  = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['c']);

$k  = $k    != NULL ? "AND (native_name LIKE '%".$k."%' OR unique_name LIKE '%".$k."%')" : "";
$a      = $a    !=0 ? "AND auth_id=".$a : "";
$l      = $l    !=0 ? "AND lang_id=".$l : "";
if(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['c']) !=0) {
$query  = "
        SELECT
            books.id,
            books.native_name,
            books.unique_name
        FROM
            book_cat_relation
        Inner Join books ON
            book_cat_relation.book_id = books.id
        WHERE
            status=1 AND
            book_cat_relation.cat_id = ".$c." ".$k." ".$a." ".$l."

";
}else{
    $query = "
        SELECT
            id,
            native_name,
            unique_name
        FROM
            books
        WHERE
            status=1 ".$k." ".$a." ".$l."";
}
```

The below pagination code is applying the limitation but not showing the pagination and even i tried to put the page no manually its not working... please help and correct me where im wrong.

```
<?php
    $sql = mysql_query($query);
    $nr = mysql_num_rows($sql);
    if (isset($pn)) {
        $pn = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $pn);
    } else {$pn = 1;}

    $itemsPerPage = 12;
    $lastPage = ceil($nr / $itemsPerPage);

    if ($pn < 1) {$pn = 1;} else if ($pn > $lastPage) {$pn = $lastPage;}

    $centerPages = "";
    $sub1 = $pn - 1;
    $sub2 = $pn - 2;
    $add1 = $pn + 1;
    $add2 = $pn + 2;



    $limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pn - 1) * $itemsPerPage .',' .$itemsPerPage;
    $sql2 = mysql_query($query." ".$limit);
?>

<?php
    include('db.php');  // DB.

    $tbl_name="books";      //table name
    $adjacents = 5;

    $k  = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['k']);
    $a  = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['a']);
    $l  = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['l']);
    $c  = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['c']);


    $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql));
    $total_pages = $total_pages['num'];

    /* Setup vars for query. */
    $targetpage = "page.php";   //your file name  (the name of this file)
    $limit = 12;                                //how many items to show per page
    $pn = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['pn']);

    if($pn) 
        $start = ($pn - 1) * $limit;            //first item to display on this page
    else
        $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0

    /* Get data. */
    $result = mysql_query($sql2);

    /* Setup page vars for display. */
    if ($pn == 0) $pn = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
    $prev = $pn - 1;                            //previous page is page - 1
    $next = $pn + 1;                            //next page is page + 1
    $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1


    $pagination = "";
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
        //previous button
        if ($pn > 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?k=$k&c=$c&a=$a&l=$l&pn=$prev\">Prev</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">prev</span>";   

        //pages 
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $pn)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?k=$k&c=$c&a=$a&l=$l&pn=$counter\">$counter</a>";                   
            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
        {
            //close to beginning; only hide later pages
            if($pn < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))      
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $pn)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?k=$k&c=$c&a=$a&l=$l&pn=$counter\">$counter</a>";                   
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?k=$k&c=$c&a=$a&l=$l&pn=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?k=$k&c=$c&a=$a&l=$l&pn=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";     
            }
            //in middle; hide some front and some back
            elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $pn && $pn > ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?k=$k&c=$c&a=$a&l=$l&pn=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?k=$k&c=$c&a=$a&l=$l&pn=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "....";
                for ($counter = $pn - $adjacents; $counter <= $pn + $adjacents; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $pn)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?k=$k&c=$c&a=$a&l=$l&pn=$counter\">$counter</a>";                   
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?k=$k&c=$c&a=$a&l=$l&pn=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?k=$k&c=$c&a=$a&l=$l&pn=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";     
            }
            //close to end; only hide early pages
            else
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?k=$k&c=$c&a=$a&l=$l&pn=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?k=$k&c=$c&a=$a&l=$l&pn=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $pn)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?k=$k&c=$c&a=$a&l=$l&pn=$counter\">$counter</a>";                   
                }
            }
        }

        //next button
        if ($pn < $counter - 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?k=$k&c=$c&a=$a&l=$l&pn=$next\">Next</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next</span>";
        $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
    }
?>

    <?=$pagination?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `if (isset($pn)) {$pn = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $pn);` be `if (isset($_GET['pn'])) {$pn = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['pn']);`. Right now you are not defining `$pn` using `$_GET['pn']`.

Comment: i tried it but nothing happened.       $pn = $_GET['pn'] is mentioned in the file thats why i was using $pn

Comment: What do you mean 'nothing happened'? You get a white page, your browser doesn't respond? Please be a little more descriptive. Does your page load, but it only show the first page? Does it not show the pagenation links?

Comment: i mean it did not show the pagination... issue is it is not showing the pagination no and also it is not working by putting the pn=2 or pn=1 in the url manually

Comment: Just noticed `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { echo $pagination;}`. So looking for `$result` you have `$result = mysql_query($sql2);` which is basically `$result = mysql_query(mysql_query($query." ".$limit));` since `$sql2 = mysql_query($query." ".$limit);`. So `$result` is `false` as a query on a query fails, so your `while()` loop never runs, so your pagination never is echoed. Not sure why your pagination is in a loop anyways.

Comment: sorry it was by mistake .... in the place of while,, this <?=$pagination?> should be there i updated also